# Merging cursor only gives back first cursor in clickEvent

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

Passing the cursor of position clicked but when doing so log is showing me I am getting only the first row no matter where I click.

```
holder.mTopCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onTopListClick(cursor);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("FROMCLICK", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
                }
            }
        });
```

The log inside the CursorAdapter onClickListener is showing only the first rows cursor even if I click 20 rows down the list.

```
@Override
    public void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor) {
        Log.i("FistClickBeforePassing", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        BottomFragment bottomFragment = (BottomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
        bottomFragment.refreshList(cursor);
    }
```

Same thing here before passing to the BottomFragment.

```
public void refreshList(Cursor cursor) {
        Log.i("RIGHTBEFOREREFRESH", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
        Log.i("REFRESHLISTNUMBER", mEmployeeNumber);
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        mNewBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                /*"Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +*/
                "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mEmployeeNumber + " ORDER BY " +
                "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
        Log.i("THECURSOR ", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(mNewBottomCursor));
        BottomListCursorAdapter bottomListCursorAdapter = new BottomListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        bottomListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(mNewBottomCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomListCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

Get the same cursor here for the log but do not get the same employee_number the cursor has for the REFRESHLISTNUMBER log statement. That is a random number from the list.

Not sure why the cursor isnt being passed correctly. I have a details button on each row that displays info from the cursor for each row and that is displaying correctly.

Completed Top Adapter

```
public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public interface TopListClickListener {
        void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor);
    }

    private TopListClickListener mCallback;

    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        if(!(context instanceof TopListClickListener)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Content must implement BottomListClickListener");
        }
        this.mCallback = (TopListClickListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_top, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mTopCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopHomeScreenCV);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mPayrollTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mPayrollTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }


        final int position = cursor.getPosition();
        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Employee_number"));
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("First_name"));
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Last_name"));
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Payroll_title"));
                String mPic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ThumbnailData"));
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Email"));
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone_mobile"));
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone_office"));
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Cost_center_id"));
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Has_direct_reports"));
                String mManagerNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Manager_employee_number"));
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Manager_employee_number", mManagerNumber);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mTopCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onTopListClick(cursor);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("FROMCLICK", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mTopCardView;
    }
}

public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    Cursor mTopCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    ListView mTopListView;
    TopListCursorAdapter mTopAdapter;
    MatrixCursor customCursor1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_list, container, false);
        String table = "employees";
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        customCursor1 = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "Employee_number", "First_name",
                "Last_name", "Payroll_title", "ThumbnailData", "Email", "Phone_mobile", "Phone_office", "Cost_center_id",
                "Has_direct_reports", "Manager_employee_number"});
        int mStartingEmployeeID = mStartingNumber;
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        mTopAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(mTopAdapter);
        return view;

    }

    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(11)});

            MergeCursor newCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{mTopCursor, customCursor1});
            mTopAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
            mTopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            scrollMyListToBottom();
            customCursor1.close();
        } cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    private void scrollMyListToBottom() {
        mTopListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTopListView.setSelection(mTopAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe something is happening with my MergeCursor in TopFragment that is messing with the curors? If so, not sure how to fix it or why it would be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a line of code to the setClickListener of the mTopCardView in the TopListCursorAdapter.

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```